# Windows 8 keeps asking for Admin password for one specific program

Tags: windows-8, security, permissions, administrator, uac

I am admin of a Windows 8 PC. I turned UAC off so other users can open programs without my permission and it works perfectly for all the software, however there is this one program (Backgammon Masters) which is an online game that whenever another (non-admin) user tries to open it, it asks for my password (Admin Password).

I also tried giving full control of the program in security tab but no luck. I even tried changing Windows Smartscreen settings but that didn't work too.

Is there any chance of giving the permission? Is it because it's an online game or because the developer is unknown?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any chance of giving the permission? Is it because it's an online game or because the developer is unknown?

Neither. A login prompt when starting a problem means the following:

The user has access to the shortcut, but the target of the shortcut is in a restricted area the user does not have access to and thus requires a login to get the access necessary.

This can happen if you install a game onto your desktop or my documents folder, because your profile is only accessible to you, no one else.

You could possibly locate the folder, and give the Users group rights, but if the game is really inside your profile (and I suspect it is, otherwise other programs/games would have also been mentioned in your question), I strongly suggest to uninstall the game, and reinstall it to a different folder, such as Program Files, or c:\games or anything that is accessible to all your users.

Comment: thanks for your help but the game is installed on the drive where all other programs are installed and every other file or program on that drive can be accessed by the user (it has nothing to do with My Documents or even windows drive) . also I double checked the access settings and the user have full control access to both shortcut and the target.